# RC script to Lua table

Tags: lua, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim, lua-table, rc

I would like to convert this vimrc script to lua.

```
let g:clipboard = {
  \   'name': 'WslClipboard',
  \   'copy': {
  \      '+': 'clip.exe',
  \      '*': 'clip.exe',
  \    },
  \   'paste': {
  \      '+': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
  \      '*': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
  \   },
  \   'cache_enabled': 0,
  \ }
```

So far I've done this, but I'm struggling with the string operators:

```
vim.g.clipboard = {
    name = 'WslClipboard',
    copy = {
        '+' = 'clip.exe',
        '*' = 'clip.exe',
    },
    paste = {
        '+' = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
        '*' = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
    },
    cache_enabled = 0,
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to set WSL clipboard for neovim.
If anyone has a better approach/method, it's welcome too.

I'm following a neovim wiki [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl) and lua guide [here](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out. For anyone searching for an answer:

```
if vim.fn.has("wsl") == 1 then
    vim.g.clipboard = {
        name = "WslClipboard",
        copy = {
            ["+"] = "clip.exe",
            ["*"] = "clip.exe",
        },
        paste = {
            ["+"] = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
            ["*"] = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
        },
        cache_enabled = 0,
    }
end
```

Here is the official [Neovim's clipboard solution](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl) for WSL written in Lua.